# What's the strategy for creating index for this query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoose

I have a comment model for each thread,

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: { type: ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'User' },
    thread: { type: ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'Thread' },
    parent: { type: ObjectID, required: true, ref: 'Comment' },
    text: { type: String, required: true },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

Besides a single query via `_id`, I want to query the database via this way:

Range query

```
const query = {
    thread: req.query.threadID,
    _id: { $gt: req.query.startFrom }
};

CommentModel.find(query).limit(req.query.limit);
```

My intention here is to find comments which related to a thread then get part of the result. It seems this query works as expected. My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to fulfill my requirement?
2. How to proper index the fields? Is this a compound index or I need to separate indexing each field? I checked the result of `explain()`, it seems as long as one of the query fields contains an index, the `inputStage.stage` will always have `IXSCAN` rather than `COLLSCAN`? Is this the key information to check the performace of the query?
3. Does it mean that every time I need to find based on one field, I need to make an index for these fields? Let's say that I want to search all the comments that are posted by an author to a specific thread.

Code like this:

```
const query = {
    thread: req.query.threadID,
    author: req.query.authorID,
};
```

Do I need to create a compound index for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query by multiple fields then you have to create *compound index*.

for example

```
const query = {
    thread: req.query.threadID,
    author: req.query.authorID,
};
```

if you want to use this query then you have to create compound index like :

```
db.comments.createIndex( { "thread": 1, "author": 1 } );
```

Then that is, the index supports queries on the item field as well as both item and stock fields:

```
db.comments.find( { thread: "threadName" } )
db.comments.find( { thread: "threadName", author: "authorName" }
```

but not supports this one

```
db.comments.find( { author: "authorName", thread: "threadName" }
```

say if you create index for `{ "thread": 1, "author": 1, "parent": 1 }` then for bellow ordered query support index

> the `thread` field,
>
> the `thread` field and the `author` field,
>
> the `thread` field and the `author` field and the `parent` field.

But *not support* for bellow order

> the `author` field,
>
> the `parent` field, or
>
> the `author` and `parent` fields.

[For more read this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question is what about one of the field in the compound index is an ObjectID which is already an index? Do I need to add them as a compound index or I just need to add the other one as a separate index?Thanks :)

Comment: As far I know if you already added one single index  and then one compound index after that when you apply query using single index field and  compound index field combination then that will not work as compound index. so you have to add them as a compound index.