# Mongoose query indexed data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am bit confused about how the indexing of data in mongodb works.

For example I have a collection called experiences with around 15 thousand productfeeds:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("597df357c6622963cc3d834e"), "userImg" : false, "category" : "Test" }
```

Now I am indexing with MongoDB the category like this:

```
db.experiences.createIndex( { category: 1 } )
```

Then I am query the the indexed collection like this:

```
 var query = {};
 query.category = categoryVal;
 query.price = 100;
 Experiences.find(query).lean().exec(function (err, rec) {
                if(err)
                    console.log('Error at records: '+err);
                else {
                   console.log(rec);
}
```

Here I am not sure if this works or not? I am getting the retrieved data but the performance is the same as before. What's wrong with it?

Comment: you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519353/whats-the-strategy-for-creating-index-for-this-query/44520558#44520558

Answer (score 0):

To verify whether your query using the index or not, use explain on your query from mongo shell.

The [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) plan will give you whats happening behind the seen to get your data.

Comment: Ok, it is possible to combine lean() and explain(). What is the different of it?

Comment: you probably need to check that yourself within mongoose's API's